# .NET SAP Connector 3.0 connection failed

Tags: c#, frameworks, sap-dotnet-connector

I try to connect to sap using SAP .NET Connector 3.0 but gives me an error like this:

```
{
SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcCommunicationException: 
LOCATION    CPIC (TCP/IP) on local host with Unicode
ERROR       partner 'mysapserveraddress:3350' not reached
TIME        Mon Feb 22 13:05:31 2016
RELEASE     720
COMPONENT   NI (network interface)
VERSION     40
RC          -10
MODULE      nixxi.cpp
LINE        3286
DETAIL      NiPConnect2: ip:3350
SYSTEM CALL connect
ERRNO       10061
ERRNO TEXT  WSAECONNREFUSED: Connection refused
COUNTER     1
}
```

This is my app.config :

```
 <add NAME="APD" USER="user" PASSWD="pass" CLIENT="xx" LANG="EN" 
          ASHOST="mysapserveraddress" SYSNR="xx" MAX_POOL_SIZE="100" GROUP="xx"
          IDLE_TIMEOUT="10"/>
```

In this config doesn't have any port, only my sap address. But in the  give me partner 'mysapserveraddress:3350' not reached.
I don't understand what is that port 3350. Any idee?

Comment: port 3350 is in the range for connections to the SAP gateway for CPIC and RFC connections, so that is ok. Can you resolve the server name with nslookup?

Comment: No i can resolve with nslookup, is a closed network with no outside access

Comment: "No" means you can't resolve the server name? So how would the NCo library resolve the name without access to a DNS server? Did you try connecting to an IP address instead of the hostname?

Comment: The port is determined using the system number. Double-check whether the system number really is 50.

Comment: I try with ip and server name But it gives the same error

Comment: Any idee how to skip the port? Maybe make a connection without using port?

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows that the target host was reached. So this is no network issue. But there is no process running on that host which listens to the specified port 3350. Therefore the connection is refused.
An ABAP application server with instance number 50 has to run on the target host whose SAP gateway process should then listen to the port 3350. Check your SAP environment and configuration.

See also this FAQ:
https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SI/What+is+the+meaning+of+the+different+network+error+messages